# Clear Entity Framework context on exception

Tags: entity-framework, ninject

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC website, and am using Entity Framework to save/update data into my database.

I am using ninject to inject dbContext into my repository class like below:

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    MyContext _context;

    public MyRepository(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // more code ...
```

This is how I am injecting the context using ninject:

```
kernel.Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

And I am using the injected dbContext as below to save the data into my database:

```
public void InsertModel(MyModel r)
{
    _context.MyModel.Add(r);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now, **the problem I am facing** is that if an exception occurs (for example if I purposely pass an invalid Model), Entity Framework will throw an exception. The invalid entity remains in the dbContext and all further *save* attempts will fail because of that.

I have been googling this issue and found [This Article](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/c1bff938-1789-4501-8161-3f38bc465a8b.aspx) which suggests putting *save / update* operation in a `try` / `catch` block. If any exception occurs, it suggests to clear dbContext in the `catch` block.

Is this the correct appraoch? It sounds like a lot of work to put a `try` / `catch` around every *save* operation and clear the dbContext? I Would appreciate any help on explaining the correct approach for clearing the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create one dbContext per Web Request. Don't share your dbContext among different requests: [dbContext lifecycle management](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/12/20/proper-sessiondbcontext-lifecycle-management/)

dbContext is Lightweight and is not expensive to create, so don't worry about performance: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx#0cb87d0d-0981-48f1-ab1a-6fc0fdfa5e9f_c)

If you are using ninject, you can use *InRequestScope* instead of *InSingletonScope*. *InRequestScope* will ensure the lifetime of your Entity Framework dbContext does not exceed the lifetime of your Http WebRequest and dispose your dbContext at the end of each request.

```
kernel.Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

**Side Note**: If you are using Repository pattern, make sure you use *InRequestScope* for your repository as well. Repository is dependant on dbContext, and you will run into problem, if your dbContext is disposed while the Repository is still in use.

```
kernel.Bind<IMyRepository>().To<MyRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

Comment: I am having same problem as described by @Esfandiyar, I tried to use InRequestScope(), but can't get it working. I am using generic repository, and my binding code is 

"kernel.Bind(typeof(IGenericRepository<>)).To(typeof(GenericRepository<>))". 

But my context is not being destroyed per request. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Are you adding InRequestScope to your ninject binding: kernel.Bind(typeof(IGenericRepository<>)).To(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).InRequestScope()

Answer (score 1):

> Would appreciate any help on explaining the correct approach for clearing the context.

Your DbContext should be scoped to a single Web Request, and will be destroyed at the end of the request.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code after your exception!

```
foreach (var dbEntityEntry in _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToArray()) {
    if (dbEntityEntry.Entity != null) {
        dbEntityEntry.State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Detached;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).